# The role of Anticipation in acquisition, consolidation, retrieval of memory

Tags: memory, long-term-memory, working-memory

I was wondering if there is any neurological/neuropsychological difference between the anticipation of an event to come, and the remembrance of that event.

More specifically, is there any difference between when (I remember|think of) some future event, and the remembrance of a past event ?

What is the role of anticipation, withstanding the valence of that event, in the workings of memory? Are the same brain structure involved ?

Comment: I remember reading in my psych textbook about schemas, that if your schema is violated, you remember the event a lot more. I'll see if I can dig it up.

Comment: By neurological/neuropsychological, do you mean differences in the loci of neural activity?  You may want to look into prospective memory, which is the specific type of memory that deals with things in the future (often things you will or need to do).

Comment: I'll look into prospective memory. Thanks.